# Not able to resolve Autocomplete or name resolving Places API PlaceAutocomplete: Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

Tags: android

Google Places API is activated, all other MAP services are working as expected, except for Places API. Any suggestions are highly appreciated

```
PlaceAutocomplete: Error getting autocomplete prediction 
API call: Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}
```

Using the version 16.0.0 of google play services

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Google play services places library is obsolete now, you have to follow the migration guide (https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration), it is perfectly explained in the first answer of this thread [How to resolve PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED in Place Autocomplete Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669261/how-to-resolve-places-api-access-not-configured-in-place-autocomplete-fragment). It worked fine for me.